# React native navigation - Child not updating on parent update

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I've edited a little bit the example from the [react navigation official guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html), in order to simulate a state change after 1 second in the HomeScreen.

I can't understand why the DetailScreen is not rerenderer when the parent screen state changes. Any way to obtain such behaviour?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  state = { value: 10 }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Click"
          onPress={() => {
            const { value } = this.state;
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', { value });
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.setState({ value: value + 1 })
            }, 1000);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const value = navigation.getParam('value');
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Detail Screen</Text>
        <Text>{value}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Detail: DetailScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

Snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/HkjOhnf04)

Answer (score 3):

**Why your code isn't working:**

You're passing `value` as a navigation prop from `Home` to `Details`. Unlike regular props, changing the value of a navigation prop in `Home` doesn't cause the value of the navigation prop itself to change. So if `Home` were a parent component that had `Details` as a child component, like this:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  ...
  <DetailsScreen
    value: this.state.value
  />
  ...
}
```

then when `this.state.value` changes in `Home`, `this.props.value` automatically changes in `Details`. However, since `Home` and `Details` have a sibling relationship in the stack navigator, you aren't able to pass `value` as a regular prop; the only way to pass a prop from `Home` to `Details` is, as you've done, as a navigation param. The problem is that when you pass `value` as you've done:

```
const { value } = this.state;
this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', { value });
```

updating `this.state.value` in `Home` does *not* cause `this.props.navigation.getParam('value')` to automatically update. So in your code:

```
const value = navigation.getParam('value');
<Text>{value}</Text>
```

`value` remains what it was when it was initially passed.

**SOLUTION**

There are several possible workarounds, like manually forcing a re-render after the `setTimeout` or re-structuring your component hierarchy to make `Home` the parent of `Details`. However, I think the best way to solve the problem while preserving the structure of your app is the following:

Instead of holding `this.state.value` in `Home`, hold it in `App`. This follows the general principle that it's easier for a child to update a parent's state variables (or vice versa) than it is for a component to update its sibling's state variables.

**Update to `App` component**

Since `App` is an `AppContainer`, you'll need to pass this.state.value to `Details` via screenprops. When you create any kind of navigator, screenprops are the way to pass variables to all the components in the navigator. So your `App` component will now look like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {value: 10} // state in App now instead of Home

  updateValue = (value) => { // method to update App's state, passed to children
    this.setState({value})
  }

  render() {
    return <AppContainer screenProps={{
      parentState: this.state,
      updateValue: this.updateValue
    }}/>;
  }

}
```

**Update to `Home` component**

The only thing you'll change in your `Home` component will be the `onPress` function. First, you won't pass `value` as a navigation prop anymore since you'll be accessing the value as a screenProps passed from `App` to all screens, rather than as a navigation prop passed from `Home` to `Details`. Second, instead of updating `this.state` of `Home` you'll be calling `this.props.screenProps.updateValue()` to update the state in `App`. So the `onPress` in your `Home` component will now look like this:

```
onPress={() => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail'); // no navigation prop
  setTimeout(() => {
    screenProps.updateValue(screenProps.appState.value + 1) // updating state of App rather than state of Home
  }, 1000);
}}
```

**Update to `Details` component**

The only change to `Details` is that rather than displaying `this.props.navigation.getParam('value')`, you'll be displaying `this.props.screenProps.appState.value` since we're now getting `value` from the screenProps from `App` instead of as a navigation prop from `Home`. So your `Details` component will now look like this:

```
class DetailScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { screenProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Detail Screen</Text>
        <Text>{screenProps.appState.value}</Text> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**WHOLE NEW CODE**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  state = { value: 10 }
  render() {
    const { screenProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Click"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail'); // no navigation prop
            setTimeout(() => {
              screenProps.updateValue(screenProps.appState.value + 1) // updating state of App rather than state of Home
            }, 1000);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { screenProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Detail Screen</Text>
        <Text>{screenProps.appState.value}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Detail: DetailScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {value: 10} // state in App now instead of Home

  updateValue = (value) => { // method to update App's state, passed to children
    this.setState({value})
  }

  render() {
    return <AppContainer screenProps={{
      appState: this.state,
      updateValue: this.updateValue
    }}/>;
  }

}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but using this pattern the possibility to use PureComponents is lost, since the shallow comparison doesn't inspect the screenProps values.

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't used PureComponents :)